# How to update value in JSON object using NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js

Here is how my **json** looks:

```
{
  Name:
    {
      "a": 2,
      "b": "hello"
    }
}
```

Here is how my **nodejs** file looks:

```
jsonfilename[Name].a = 12;
jsonfilename[Name].b = "bye";
```

Im not sure why it's not updating it!
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Only use [square brackets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) when you are trying to use an expression to access a property. If you know the name of the property just use [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation):

```
jsonfilename.Name.a = 12;
jsonfilename.Name.b = "bye";
```

If you use bracket notation then you must include an expression that evaluates to a string or Symbol. In your case you want the string "Name":

```
jsonfilename["Name"].a = 12;
jsonfilename["Name"].b = "bye";
```